# How to stop a soft keyboard to overlap on my button

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

```
<Button android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_app_btn"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="@string/next"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:id="@+id/login_nxt_btn"
        />
```

Sorry I am new here. I have this problem, whenever I open my soft keyboard on my EditText, the soft keyboard overlaps on this button. But after a few seconds the button will show above the soft keyboard.

I wanted to make this button to be above on the soft-keyboard whenever I open my soft keyboard. I have tried everything that says on the internet. Like `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"` but still no luck. I have tried also put `ScrollView` Hoping someone could help me.

Comment: have you tried `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` ?

Comment: try with adjustResize. If your button is at bottom and if you are using scrollview. Make your scrollview above your button. This will solve your issue.

Comment: Hi guys, yes i have already tried the adjustResize and i have already tried layout_above my button at the bottom

Comment: can you post full code of xml file so i can help you

Comment: @Arti here sir https://pastebin.com/2QdcZ2cd

Comment: try using nestedscrollview with android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Comment: I have try your xml code and I have just put on android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden" in ManiFest file and It's Working

Answer (score 1):

Use Relative layout in your xml and the below property will work. add this property in your manifest activity tag.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Comment: i am using a constraintlayout with a linear layout child and i have already tried that on the manifest sir still no luck

Answer (score 0):

You can simply switch your Activity's windowSoftInputModeflag to adjustPan in your AndroidMainfest.xml file inside your activity tag.

```
<activity
   ...
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> 
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use next variant in XML:

```
<activity
   ...
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"> 
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below code, it worked for me,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttomButtom"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:hint="Hello World!" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttomButtom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:text="Bottom Button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Also you have to mention inputmode in manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible"
```

Here's the video which worked for me
[image]

Comment: I am trying ti now sir.

Comment: Thank you for your time sir and willingness to help, but on my scenario it does not work. I am really appreciate this sir.

Comment: share full layout, so that it will be easy to understand, and resolve your issue

Comment: But this is what i wanted sir

Comment: https://pastebin.com/2QdcZ2cd here's the whole layout sir @akshay

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
   <NestedScrollView
    --your other view
   </NestedScrollView>
   <Button />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```